# Javascript Book for free Download

Tags: javascript

i'm lookin for a good javascript pdf book. which i can download freely.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/), is more than a *free book*, it contains a lot of examples and an environment to try them out and play with them.

Also, give a look to [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687566/learning-javascript-in-one-weekend/2687693#2687693) of *really good* resources to learn the language.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.freeprogrammingresources.com/jscriptbook.html

Answer (score 0):

[W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp) is good for starters and it is free!

Comment: i don't think one should use w3schools. it's pooly written and full of errors (for more information, take a look at http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/) by Rebecca Murphey:

> jQuery is fast becoming a must-have skill for front-end developers. The purpose of this book is to provide an overview of the jQuery JavaScript library; when you're done with the book, you should be able to complete basic tasks using jQuery, and have a solid basis from which to continue your learning. This book was designed as material to be used in a classroom setting, but you may find it useful for individual study.
>
> This is a hands-on class. We will spend a bit of time covering a concept, and then you’ll have the chance to work on an exercise related to the concept. Some of the exercises may seem trivial; others may be downright daunting. In either case, there is no grade; the goal is simply to get you comfortable working your way through problems you’ll commonly be called upon to solve using jQuery. Example solutions to all of the exercises are included in the sample code.